# C# LINQ separate row into two rows based on List<String> property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `IPInfo` objects already filtered in some way. My problem is to separate records based on last `List<String>` property:

```
class IPInfo
{
    public String TRADE_DATE; 
    public String CUSTOMER_NAME;
    public List<String> ORIGINAL_IP;
    public List<String> LOGON_IP = new List<String>();
}
```

`List<IPInfo> fields` when exported to `.xls` file looks like this:

[image]

I need each `Logon IP` record to be in a separate row, but `Original IP` to remain combined. On a picture, for `CITI` I need:

```
----------------------------------------------
10.55.13.104     |   128.110.34.102
128.110.34.102   |
----------------------------------------------
10.55.13.104     |   10.55.13.104
128.110.34.102   |
```

Any help?

**EDIT:**
this query was applied before to combine duplicated `Logon IP`s. But, as I told, I need `Logon IP`s separated

```
    private static List<IPInfo> selectFields(ref List<IPInfo> fields)
    {
        var distinct =
            fields
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.TRADE_DATE, x.CUSTOMER_NAME })
                .Select(y => new IPInfo()
                {
                    TRADE_DATE = y.Key.TRADE_DATE,
                    CUSTOMER_NAME = y.Key.CUSTOMER_NAME,
                    ORIGINAL_IP = y.SelectMany(x => x.ORIGINAL_IP).Distinct().ToList(),
                    LOGON_IP = y.SelectMany(x => x.LOGON_IP).Distinct().ToList()
                })
                .ToList();

        return distinct;
    }
```

Comment: Is there always the same number of entries in `ORIGINAL_IP` as there is in `LOGON_IP`? Do you want to match the first `ORIGINAL_IP` with the first `LOGON_IP`, the second with the second etc.?

Comment: `ORIGINAL_IP` should contain all possible original IPs for a given customer. `LOGON_IP` should only contain one IP which customer actually used to logon

Comment: But your second example row doesn't show that. It's really not clear what you are asking. Can you give some example input and what you expect the output would be?

Comment: The second row is the problem: customer logged twice, and I need 2 rows for both events

Comment: I'll say again, please give input and output examples. Perhaps start with the real source, what is in the `fields` variable here?

Comment: Do you mean: `foreach ip in ipinfos{ foreach logip in ip.LOGON_IP { newlist.Add(new IPInfo{ blahproperty = ip.blahproperty, blahlogon = logip } }` ? If so, just do it with a couple of loops, stop trying to make everything LINQ - the problem in not knowing how to LINQ it now is that you won't understand it enough to come back later and make changes. LINQ might be a really useful hammer, but not every problem in C# is a nail

Comment: @Caius Jard, thank you, that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var distinct = fields
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.TRADE_DATE, x.CUSTOMER_NAME })
        .Select(y => {
            var logonIps = y.SelectMany(x => x.LOGON_IP).Distinct().ToList();

            foreach (var logonIp in logonIps)
            {
                return new IPInfo(){
                    TRADE_DATE = y.Key.TRADE_DATE,
                    CUSTOMER_NAME = y.Key.CUSTOMER_NAME,
                    ORIGINAL_IP = y.SelectMany(x => x.ORIGINAL_IP).Distinct().ToList(),
                    LOGON_IP = logonIp
                };
            }
        })
        .ToList();

return distinct;
```

Loop through the logonIP list and treat it as new row for each logonIP.

Comment: Shows error - CS0029 `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`, on `LOGON_IP = logonIp` line

Comment: @user2376997 Change class IPInfo -> LOGON_IP, from List<string> to string type, if there is no other usage

Comment: Makes sense, but the query wont work anyway, because it is treated as a List `var logonIps = y.SelectMany(x => x.LOGON_IP).Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't realize it was a List type when I giving the answer, I edited my answer, I retrieve the string in the list at first then loop through it

Comment: actually, your first answer is correct, I just tried `LOGON_IP = { logip };`